# Circle rotations are conjugate by a homeomorphism iff $\alpha = \pm \beta$ mod 1

Tags: dynamical-systems

Let $R_\alpha(s)=s+\alpha $ mod 1, likewise for $R_\beta$  be the circle rotations on the unit interval.
Prove that $R_\alpha$ and $R_\beta$ are conjugate by a homeomorphism iff $\alpha = \pm \beta$ mod 1.

From Brin & Stuck: Introduction to dynamical systems 1.2.4

My effort:

$\impliedby$

Let by definition of modulus, $\alpha = \beta + k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Then
\begin{align}
R_\alpha(s) &= s+ \alpha~(\text{mod 1})\\
&=s+ \alpha + k_1\\
&= s+(\beta + k_2) + k_1\\
&= s+\beta + k_1 +k_2\\
&= s+\beta~(\text{mod 1})\\
&= R_\beta(s)
\end{align}
Therefore, I define $h(s) = Id_{[0,1)}$, the identity on the unit interval, which is an homeomorphism. Thus $h \circ R_\alpha = R_\beta \circ h$ and h conjugates the circle rotations.

Now let $\alpha = -\beta + k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
\begin{align}
R_\alpha(s) &= s+ \alpha~(\text{mod 1})\\
&=s+ \alpha + k_1\\
&= s+(-\beta + k_2) + k_1\\
&= s-\beta + k_1 +k_2\\
&= s-\beta~(\text{mod 1})\\
&= -(-s+\beta~(\text{mod 1}))\\
&= -R_\beta(-s)~\qquad\qquad\qquad (*)
\end{align}

Then to be conjugations we must have an homeomorphism $h$ such that

\begin{align}
h \circ R_\alpha &= R_\beta \circ h\\
h(R_\alpha(s)) &= R_\beta(h(s))~\text{if we plug in (*)}\\
h(-R_\beta(-s)) &= R_\beta(h(s))\\
h(-R_\beta(-s)) &=h(s)+ \beta~\text{mod 1}
\end{align}

Now I am not sure how to continue as I am not able to construct an function $h$ from the last expression that would be an homeomorphism.

**EDIT 1: WRONG**

The function $h(s) = -Id_{[0,1)}$ works in this case and is a homeomorphism.

Now the other way.

$\implies$

Let $h$ be an homeomorphism s.t the unit rotations $R_\alpha$ and $R_\beta$ are conjugate.
There exist lifts for the rotations denoted $r_\alpha$ and $r_\beta$, and thus for the homeomorphism h, denoted $H$ that conjugates the lift rotations. I assume that the lift is preserved under direction and increasing, therefore $H(s+1) = H(s) + 1$.
Then
\begin{align}
r_\alpha(s) &= H^{-1}(r_\beta(H(s)))\\
&= H^{-1}(H(s) + \beta)
\end{align}

Then follows
\begin{align}
H(r_\alpha(s)) &= H(s) + \beta\\
H(s+ \alpha) &= H(s) +\beta \\
\end{align}

Then, because we have the property of preservation of direction for $H$ that $\alpha=\beta$ for the lift and thus $\alpha=\beta \text{mod 1}$ for the rotations.

For the second case I assume that the lift is preserved under direction and decreasing, therefore $H(s+1) = H(s) - 1$.

Following the same argument, I get

\begin{align}
H(r_\alpha(s)) &= H(s) + \beta\\
H(s+ \alpha) &= H(s) +\beta \\
\end{align}

and therefore $\alpha = -\beta$ for the lift and $\alpha = - \beta~\text{mod 1}$ for the rotations.

Combining results returns $\alpha = \pm \beta~\text{mod 1}$

**EDIT 2:**

> Then, because we have the property of preservation of direction for $H$ that $\alpha=\beta$ for the lift and thus $\alpha=\beta \text{mod 1}$ for the rotations.

This is not a correct statement. I redo the prove.

$\implies$

> Let $h$ be an homeomorphism s.t the unit rotations $R_\alpha$ and $R_\beta$ are conjugate.
>   There exist lifts for the rotations denoted $r_\alpha$ and $r_\beta$, and thus for the homeomorphism h, denoted $H$ that conjugates the lift rotations. I assume that the lift is preserved under direction and increasing, therefore $H(s+1) = H(s) + 1$.

From the definition of $r_\alpha$ and the conjugacy we can express the conjugacy in terms of $r^n_\alpha$,
\begin{equation}
H \circ r^n_\alpha = r^n_\beta \circ H.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
H \circ r^n_\alpha &= r^n_\beta \circ H \\
H \circ r^n_\alpha &= H(s) +n \cdot \beta\\
\frac{H(r^n_\alpha(s)) - H(s)}{n} &= \beta
\end{align}

Because the conjugacy holds for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we can take the limit of $n\to \infty$,

\begin{align}
\beta &= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(r^n_\alpha(s)) - H(s)}{n}\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(r^n_\alpha(s))}{n} - \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(s)}{n}\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} - \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(s)}{n}
\end{align}

The second quotient is independent of $n$, $H(s)$ is bounded, and therefore the quotient converges towards zero.

We use the squeeze thereom to determine the first quotient.

Because $\alpha$ is irrational, $\lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor$ and $\lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil$ are integers and $\lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor \leq n\cdot \alpha \leq \lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil$.

Therefore, using the preservation of direction,

\begin{align}
H(s + \lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor) &\leq& H(s +n \cdot \alpha) &\leq& H(s + \lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil)\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s + \lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor)}{n} &\leq& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} &\leq& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s + \lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil)}{n}\\
\alpha\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s + \lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor)}{n\cdot \alpha} &\leq& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} &\leq& \alpha\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s + \lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil)}{n\cdot \alpha}\\
\alpha\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s) + \lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor}{n\cdot \alpha} &\leq& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} &\leq& \alpha\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s) + \lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil}{n\cdot \alpha}
\end{align}

Once again, $H(s)$ is bounded and independent of $n$while $\frac{\lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor}{n\cdot \alpha}\to 1$, thus follows
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s) + \lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor}{n\cdot \alpha} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s)}{n \cdot \alpha} + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor}{n\cdot \alpha}
= 0 + 1 = 1
\end{equation}

Because $\frac{\lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil}{n \cdot \alpha} \to 1$ we can conclude
\begin{align}
\alpha\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s) + \lfloor n\cdot \alpha \rfloor}{n\cdot \alpha} &\leq& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} &\leq& \alpha\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s) + \lceil n\cdot \alpha \rceil}{n\cdot \alpha}\\
\alpha \cdot (0+1)&\leq& \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} \leq \alpha \cdot (0+1)
\end{align}

Therfore we can conclude that

\begin{equation}
\beta = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(s +n \cdot \alpha)}{n} - \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{H(s)}{n} = \alpha - 0 = \alpha
\end{equation}

Thus, $\beta = \alpha$, and returning to the original rotations, we conclude $\beta = \alpha~\text{(mod(1))}$.

The result for $\beta = -\alpha~\text{(mod(1))}$ follows when we assume that the lift is preserved under direction and decreasing, therefore $H(s+1) = H(s) - 1$

Comment: You can take $h=-\text{id}$, but you still need to take care of the other direction.

Comment: Ouch, how did I not notice that $h = -$Id was the other solution.. I am aware that I need to do $\Rightarrow$ aswell. I Will edit that in.

Comment: @JohnB I edited the reverse direction, would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: You should have a look at the sentence "Then, because we have the property of preservation of direction for $H$ that $\alpha=\beta$ for the lift and thus $\alpha=\beta \text{mod 1}$ for the rotations." It makes no sense since we only know that $H(t+1)=H(t)+1$.

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed then, do you have a hint?

Comment: Do have a look at Brin-Stuck, but it depends on what you learned or can use. True, the rotations preserve orientation.